# SSH AuthorizedKeysCommand and SELinux

Tags: ssh, selinux, sshd

I'm trying to use the SSH `AuthorizedKeysCommand` in a CentOS 6.5 machine, but I'm encountering an SELinux error.  When I switch SELinux to permissive mode - using `setenforce 0` - it works, but when I turn SELinux back to enforcing, the command no longer works.

I get the following readout in my audit log (all one line):

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1404210795.382:917): avc: denied { execute } for pid=2924 comm="sshd"
name="get-keys" dev=dm-0 ino=167467 scontext=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
tcontext=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tclass=file
```

The SELinux policy for the `get-keys` command was different before. I set it to the same settings as the `sshd` command. I've also tried setting all SSH-relevant SELinux Booleans to true - all the ones I could find with `grep`:

```
$ getsebool -a | grep ssh
allow_ssh_keysign --> on
fenced_can_ssh --> on
ssh_chroot_full_access --> on
ssh_chroot_manage_apache_content --> on
ssh_chroot_rw_homedirs --> on
ssh_sysadm_login --> on
```

`/usr/bin/get-ssh-keys/` contains the `get-keys` command.  Here are the permissions for that directory:

```
$ ls -laZ /usr/bin/get-ssh-keys/
drwxr--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:etc_t:s0   .
dr-xr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0       ..
-rwx--x--x. root root system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 get-keys

[...]

$ ls -laZ /usr/
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0       .
dr-xr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:root_t:s0      ..

[...]
```

And here are the relevant `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` settings:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/bin/get-ssh-keys/get-keys
AuthorizedKeysCommandRunAs root
```

The `get-keys` command is connecting over a socket to another server as well as writing to log files in `/var/log/get-ssh-keys/error_log`. Maybe that's why SELinux is preventing access, but I don't think so.

Is there something plainly obvious I'm missing?

There's some confusion about the `AuthorizedKeysCommand`. It doesn't actually read keys from the `~/.ssh/` directory. Instead, the `AuthorizedKeysCommand` setting specifies a program that will print all keys for a given user to stdout as individual lines.

The command I've specified, `get-keys`, works with SELinux set to permissive, but fails when set to enforcing.

I get prompted for a password with SELinux enforcing, but I'm allowed to log in using the keys the command retrieves with SELinux permissive.

Comment: Try the `restorecon` command from here: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/SecuringSSH

Comment: That command sets the context for the ~/.ssh/ directory.  The AuthorizedKeysCommand won't read public key values from that directory.

Comment: Why do you need the command to run as root for any user?

Comment: The solution to this is I believe shown in this SF Q&A titled: [OpenSSH with public keys from database](http://serverfault.com/questions/162238/openssh-with-public-keys-from-database)

Answer (score -1):

Mate I'm sure you figured out already but just in case:

1. you need a tool to troubleshoot selinux 
   yum install setroubleshoot
2. see if the alert has been logged and after you review create a policy
   sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log

the tool will tell you what to do

```
[root@zabbix audit]# sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log
 49% done'list' object has no attribute 'split'
 100% done
found 1 alerts in /var/log/audit/audit.log
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/python2.7 from name_connect access on the       tcp_socket port 3306.

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that python2.7 should be allowed name_connect access on the      port 3306 tcp_socket by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# grep python /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M mypol
# semodule -i mypol.pp
```